# Adding file paths to Latex figures?

Tags: ruby, regex

In the below text I would like to add `figs/01/` to each of the 3 files. As you can see the files can either be pdf,png or not have an extension and sometimes the `\includegraphics` breaks over several lines.

My current thinking is

```
cat figs.tex | ruby -ne 'puts $_.gsub(/\\includegraphics\[.*?\]\{.*?\}/) { |x| x.do_something_here }'
```

but it is a chick and egg problem, because I would need to search again for the part to search and replace.

**Question**

Can anyone see how to solve such a situation?

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centerline{ \includegraphics[height=55mm]{plotLn} \includegraphics[height=55mm]{plotLnZoom.pdf}}
\caption{Funktionen $f(x) = \ln(x)$ \ref{examg0} (bl)}
\end{figure}
\begin{example}[Parameterfremstilling for ret linje]\label{tn6.linje}
\begin{think}
    Givet linjen $\,m\,$,
        \includegraphics[trim=1cm 11.5cm 1cm
 11.5cm,width=0.60\textwidth,clip]{vektor8.png}
\end{think}
```

Comment: Try `/\\includegraphics\[[^\]\[]*\]\{[^{}]*\}/`

Comment: What do you want to obtain for the third file: `figs/01/figs/06/vektor8.png` or `figs/01/vektor8.png` (in other words, do you want to keep the original path?)?

Comment: Wouldn't this be better asked on TeX.SE?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Ups. Now corrected in OP =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the whole file in one shot *(instead of the default behaviour that reads the file line by line)*. To do that you need the switch `-0777` (special value for the record separator). This solves the problem of a pattern that spreads over multiple lines.

You can also replace the `-n` option and `puts` with `-p` to automatically print the result.

```
ruby -0777 -pe 'gsub(/\\includegraphics\[[^\]]*\]{\K/,"figs/01/")' figs.tex
```

You can omit `$_`, by default `gsub` is applied to it. *(You can even impress your friends removing the space between `-pe` and the quote `'`)*

About the pattern, `\K` removes all on the left from the match result, the match result here is only an empty string at the expected position where the replacement string is inserted.

Note that the ruby command line options come from Perl:

```
perl -0777 -pe 's!\\includegraphics\[[^\]]*\]{\K!figs/01/!g' figs.tex
```

Comment: Very useful information about the Perl similarities! Both works perfectly. The Perl one does give `Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated`.

Comment: @JasmineLognnes: yes because Perl 6 changed this behavior (you don't need to escape it in Perl 5). Change `{` to `\{`